# Gridview selected row returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview contains linkbutton as below cod in my aspx file:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Button3" Style="float: left; margin-left: 10px"
            CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>'
            Text="cancellation" runat="server" CommandName="cancell" OnClick="Button3_Click">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-lock" title="cancellation"></i>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want when user click on link button update my database table but when I want get value of cell from gridview selected row I face by null refrence exception in line: string barcode = dgvData.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text;.

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Transaction tr = new Transaction();
    HasinReservation.Entities.Db.Transaction dt = new Transaction();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.x.x.x\Sql2008;Initial Catalog=GardeshgariKish;User ID=cms;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Update Transactions SET IsCancelled = 1 WHERE BarCodeNumber = @Value", connection);

    string barcode = dgvData.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", barcode);
    //sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: So which line is throwing the exception, and what have you done to investigate why?

Comment: in this line:
string barcode = dgvData.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text;

Comment: no is not that case, selected row property of my gridview returns null.

Comment: @saeedgarmsiri - Okay so if you are aware, you should mention that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your concern i found it. 
here is my edited asp markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Button3" Style="float: left; margin-left: 10px"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>'
                                        Text="cancellation" runat="server" **CommandName="select"** OnClick="Button3_Click">
                                                <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-lock" title="cancellation"></i>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and here is code behind:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Transaction tr = new Transaction();
            **GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;**
            HasinReservation.Entities.Db.Transaction dt = new Transaction();
            **int x = clickedRow.RowIndex;**
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.X.X.X\Sql2008;Initial Catalog=GardeshgariKish;User ID=cms;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Update Transactions SET IsCancelled = 1 WHERE BarCodeNumber = @Value", connection);

            **string barcode = dgvData.Rows[x].Cells[12].Text;**
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", barcode);

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`dgvData.SelectedRow` won't give you the row from which the button was clicked. You need `NamingContainer` for that. This should work for you:-

```
LinkButton Button3 = (LinkButton)sender;
GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)Button3.NamingContainer;
string barcode = selectedRow.Cells[12].Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

that's because you are not using the select-command

the way to go should be:

- Add the RowCommand Event to your GridView

  ```
  onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
  ```
- replace the Command Argument `id`  with BarCode and remove `OnClick="Button3_Click"`

  ```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="Button3" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("BarCode")
  ```
- receive the value

  ```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {        
      if (e.CommandName == "cancell")
      {
          string barcode = e.CommandArgument;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way to get the value from GridView. I'm not writing the entire code of yours but the error containing part.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
  {
    DataGridViewRow row = this.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string barcode = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();        
  }
}
```

But what I can see from Your code that You're using edit mode of GridView but not leveraging it into Your code. Please see this [link](http://asphelps.com/GridView/How-to-Edit-and-Update-rows-in-GridView-in-Asp.net.aspx) to To Edit And Update Rows In GridView In Asp.Net.

Answer (score 2):

[**`GridView.SelectedRow`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property will be populated with the row only when you select a row. Easiest way is to set the Property [**`autogenerateselectbutton`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true` as:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" autogenerateselectbutton="True" .../>
```

You must perform the below steps sequentially:

1. Select a row by clicking the Select Button
2. After that click the Link button. In the Button Click event now you will have your selected row as usual.

Also, `dgvData.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text` means the Cell/Column 12 should be a `BoundField`.

If Column 12 is Template Field, use the `FindControl()` method as `dgvData.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblBarCode") as Label).Text;` assuming a Label is used to display bar code etc...